# Effective type of members in a const structure instance?

Tags: c, struct, constants, member

```
typedef struct S {
    int i;
    char *pc;
} S;

void foo() {
    char str[] = "abcdefg";
    const S cs = {1, str};
    // more code
}
```

In the above example, `cs` is of type `const S`, and `cs.i` is effectively `const int i`, because I can't pass `&cs.i` to a function where it requires `int *`, but only `const int *`.

The question is, what is the effective type of `cs.pc`? Is it `const char *` or `char * const`? In other words, which of the function below can I pass `&cs.pc` to?

```
A: void foo_a(const char * * ppcc);
B: void foo_b(char * const * pcpc);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what is the designated word for the meaning of "effective type", so in case I'm wrong or I used an unsuitable expression, feel free to correct me.

Comment: Only the data in the struct is const, so only the address (the value of pc) is const. The data pc points to is not...

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but symbols beginning with an underscore and followed by an upper-case letter (like `_S`) are reserved in *all* scopes. You should not use such symbol names. In your case it's easy to fix, since structure (and unions and enumeration) tags (like your `_S`) lives in their own namespace, so you can name the structure the same as the type-alias.

Comment: ... so B should be correct.

Comment: `S` is `const`.  What `S.pc` points to is not necessarily `const`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I come from C++ so I prefer not to have struct name the same as its alias.

Comment: Well that makes even less sense to me. In C++ a structure name is also a type-name, like the alias defined with `typedef` here is. I would think that using the same name for both the structure name and the type-name in C would make it more similar to C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function takes pointer to a `const` pointer to a `char`. It has the following prototype:

```
void f(char * const *);
```

Explanation:

The `const` qualifier in `const S cs = {1, str}`; is applied to each member. For `pc`, it appies it to pointer itself, not its content<sup>1</sup>, hence its type is `char * const` (constant pointer to `char`).

Let's illustrate it by simpler example:

```
int a = 100;
int * const p = &a;
T pp = &p;
```

What is `T`? It is a type suitable for holding pointer to `const` pointer to `int`, so this `pp`'s declaration is:

```
int *const *pp = &p;
```

---

<sup>1) For that, you would have need to change struct's definition of that member with `const char *pc;`</sup>

Comment: `char const *` is identical to `const char *`.

Answer (score -1):

`const char *ptr` : means ptr should point to same address, you can't expect ptr to hold some other address.

`cs.pc` is nothing but `const char *pc`, So while passing it to function

`void foo_a(const char * * ppcc);` // will not work bcz ppcc can point to any address

thats why you should use  option B

```
void foo_b(char * const * pcpc);
```